# Prevent inline scripts in nuxt3 build

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

### Context

I'm working on a project with nuxt3 and having trouble with deployment. The app is built into 100% static files (SSR is disabled) and I need to enforce a strict CSP.

### Issue

With the default configuration, nuxt generates 2 inline script tags:

- config: specifies window.**NUXT**.config (with `runtime` and `app` config objects)
- `__NUXT_DATA__`, which seems to contain some metadata about the build (errors, serverRendered, etc...)

These clash with the CSP, which doesn't allow inline scripts.

### Expected solution

I'd like to find a way to configure nuxt so that instead of inlining these scripts, it links to static files (or just bundles them with the main script).

### Rejected solutions

I've considered and rejected a few solutions:

- [nonce](https://content-security-policy.com/nonce/): The app is served statically, so a nonce is not feasible.
- [unsafe-inline](https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-inline/): This is not acceptable (won't get through review).
- [script hash](https://content-security-policy.com/hash/): This means I'd have to manually update the CSP every time I update the app config.
- nuxt.config.ts > features > [noscript](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#noscripts): This just disables all scripts and nothing works anymore.
- nuxt.config.ts > render > [injectScripts](https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-render/#injectscripts): This seems promising, but this option is only available in nuxt2.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, what I'm looking for is not doable...
https://nuxt-security.vercel.app/documentation/advanced/strict-csp